# Thunderbird extension - unhide account.incomingServer

Tags: thunderbird-addon

I already hide one of my incomingServer:

```
var acctMgr = Cc["@mozilla.org/messenger/account-manager;1"].getService(Ci.nsIMsgAccountManager);
var accounts = acctMgr.accounts;
accounts.length; // =2

var account = accounts.queryElementAt(0, Ci.nsIMsgAccount);
account.incomingServer.hidden = true;
accounts.length; // =1
```

I lost one of my account / incomming server - which i wanted (hide account on left panel).

**Question**: How to get back this server / account?

Here i have some tip:
[hidden flag desc](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIMsgIncomingServer.idl)

The server can be retrieved from the account manager by name using the
   various Find methods, but nsIMsgAccountManager's GetAccounts and 
   GetAllServers methods won't return the server/account. - but how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I already resolve this (for: dev@gmail.com):

```
acctMgr.FindServer('dev', 'gmail.com', 'pop3').hidden = false;
```